# How to redirect without breaking filter chain in spring?

Tags: java, servlet-filters

Hi I have some existing code in my application that use a security filter

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    if (someCondition==TRUE) {
        super.doFilter(request, response, chain);
    }else{
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Now I want to redirect the user to a certain URL after the filter flow is completed. I have added the sendRedirect Method like the below example in code, but this is breaking the filter flow in some cases.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    if (someCondition==TRUE) {
     String targetURL =  request.getParameter("targetURL");
        if(targetURL != null && targetURL != "undefined") {
            LOGGER.info("redirecting to this targetURL : " + targetURL);
            response.sendRedirect(targetURL);
            // this is an internal URL and should be redirected after executing the filter flow
        } else {
            super.doFilter(request, response, chain);
        }
    }else{
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

I have a feeling that this is not correct way to redirect the User to an internal URL as it breaks the filter flow. What is correct way of redirecting to URL after filter processing has been completed?

Comment: Do you actually want to send a 302 to the user? Or do you want to process the request using a different servlet - i.e a server side redirect? https://www.baeldung.com/servlet-redirect-forward

Comment: umm not sure what exactly is best thing to do in this context but i want user to securely navigated to the target URL